# Replace loop for apply or sappy?

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, apply, sapply

I have a program, but I need to replace loop for apply or sapply? Is this possible in my case? Can you help me?

## My code

```
TD = stri_read_lines("script.R")

chars = data.frame()
for(i in 1:length(TD)){
  if(TD[i] !='') {  
    char= unlist(strsplit(TD[i], split=""))
        for ( j in 1:nchar(TD[i]) ) {     
      chars =rbind(chars , data.frame(a=char[j], b=i, c= j))
   }
  }  
}

> dput(head(TD))
"data.frame()"
```

## Result

```
   a b  c
1  d 1  1
2  a 1  2
3  t 1  3
4  a 1  4
5  . 1  5
6  f 1  6
7  r 1  7
8  a 1  8
9  m 1  9
10 e 1 10
11 ( 1 11
12 ) 1 12
```

Comment: What is `TD`?... Also please post a reproducible example along with expected output.

Comment: @Kim, I have rolled back the previous version of the question. Please do not change it completely otherwise the answers provided are not valid anymore. You are welcome to make another question as a separate one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strsplit` is already vectorized, so it's better to use it that way than in a loop.  I'll be reading in one of my own scripts, since I don't have yours.

```
library(stringi)

TD <- stri_read_lines("~/R/My Scripts/capitalize.R")
cat(TD[1:3], sep = "\n")
# capitalize_first <- function(x) {
#   # Capitalize the first word in each value of a character vector.
#   result <- as.character(x)
```

First we'll remove the blank lines.

```
TD <- TD[TD != ""]
```

Then we'll create a list, where each element is a vector of the characters in a line.  We'll also get the length of each (i.e., number of characters in a line).

```
line_characters <- strsplit(TD, "")
line_lengths <- lengths(line_characters)
```

The one column you want is all the characters in a single vector.  `unlist` does this.

```
all_characters <- unlist(line_characters)
```

Another column is the line number each character comes from. Using `rep`, we can repeat each number in the sequence 1, 2, ... once for each character in the line.

```
line_identifier <- rep(
  seq_along(line_characters),
  line_lengths
)
```

The third column is the index of the character in the line. Using `line_lengths` again, we can create a list of sequences, each from 1 to the length of its line.  Then `unlist` collapses them into a single vector.

```
index_in_line <- unlist(
  lapply(line_lengths, seq_len)
)
```

Now to just combine them in a data.frame. I've also shown a part where the data crosses lines.

```
chars <- data.frame(
  a = all_characters,
  b = line_identifier,
  c = index_in_line
)

chars[21:40, ]
#    a b  c
# 21 f 1 21
# 22 u 1 22
# 23 n 1 23
# 24 c 1 24
# 25 t 1 25
# 26 i 1 26
# 27 o 1 27
# 28 n 1 28
# 29 ( 1 29
# 30 x 1 30
# 31 ) 1 31
# 32   1 32
# 33 { 1 33
# 34   2  1
# 35   2  2
# 36 # 2  3
# 37   2  4
# 38 C 2  5
# 39 a 2  6
# 40 p 2  7
```

Comment: If you're trying to parse code, you're better off doing this: `getParseData(parse("script.R"))`.  That breaks code into tokens (smallest bits, like names and operators) with the location data.  It can also tell if an equals sign is used for assignment or setting parameters in a function.

Comment: Ok, but how do I find any character vector?

Comment: The output of `getParseData` is a data.frame.  The `text` column of it is a character vector of the token. The `token` column says what the piece of code is actually doing, so it might be more useful.  You didn't specify your goal, so I assume you're looking for assignment operators.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a compact solution with base R:

```
TD <- c("data.frame()", "", "one more line")
L <- strsplit(TD, split="")
data.frame(a=unlist(L), b=rep(1:length(TD), nchar(TD)), c=sequence(nchar(TD)))
```

Comment: I would like to use the stri_locate_all function to search for only such characters: v = c ("=", <- "), how to do it in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer using `lapply`.

```
data.frame(a = unlist(strsplit(TD, split = "")),
           b = rep(seq_along(TD), nchar(TD)),
           c = unlist(lapply(nchar(TD), seq_len)))
```

Comment: @Kim, It does find also those characters.

Comment: I would like to use the stri_locate_all function to search for only such characters: v = c ("=", <- "), how to do it in your code?